# How to improve linq performance with large collections (Code first POCO class)

Tags: c#, performance, linq

I want to calculate a optimum reservation.

When I do it in PL/SQL it is very slow and expensive. So I try to use LINQ. I have two collections, orders and stocks. But it is very slow too. it is not enough fast for me.

I can't use Compiled Query. I can't use Data Dictionary index (I don't work with unique data). `AsParallel()` didn't work (at least not for me).

How to improve performance of the code?

```
var orders = deserialize<Order>(@"C:\orders.bin");
  var stocks = deserialize<Stock>(@"C:\Stocks.bin");
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{

  var order1 = (from p in orders
                where p.QTY_DEMAND > 0
                group p by new { p.OUTER_GROUP_ID, p.ORG_CODE, p.ARTICLE_CODE, p.FROM_ACCOUNTNO, p.AVAILABILITY_STATE } into g
                select new
                {
                    OUTER_GROUP_ID = g.Key.OUTER_GROUP_ID,
                    ORG_CODE = g.Key.ORG_CODE,
                    Article_code = g.Key.ARTICLE_CODE,
                    FROM_ACCOUNTNO = g.Key.FROM_ACCOUNTNO,
                    AVAILABILITY_STATE = g.Key.AVAILABILITY_STATE,
                    QUANTITY = g.Sum(p => p.QTY_DEMAND)
                });
  var order2 = from p in order1
                join vw1 in stocks on new { org_code = p.ORG_CODE, article_code = p.Article_code, account_no = p.FROM_ACCOUNTNO, av_state = p.AVAILABILITY_STATE }
                equals new { org_code = vw1.ORG_CODE, article_code = vw1.ARTICLE_CODE, account_no = vw1.ACCOUNTNO, av_state = vw1.AVAILABILITY_STATE }
                where vw1.QTY_STOCK > 0
                group new { p, o = vw1 } by new { baseValue, vw1.LOCATION_TYPE, vw1.PLACE_TYPE, p.Article_code, p.QUANTITY, vw1.STANDS_ON_THM } into g
                let SumQTY_STOCK = g.Sum(o => o.o.QTY_STOCK)
                select new
                {
                    BASE_VALUE = g.Key.baseValue,
                    g.Key.Article_code,
                    ...
                }
   var order3 = from p in order2
                group p by new { p.BASE_VALUE, p.LOCATION_TYPE, p.PLACE_TYPE } into g
                select new
                {
                    ...
                }
   var order4 = from a in order3
                ...
   foreach (var item in order4)
   {
       //doing somethings
   }
}

public List<T> deserialize<T>(string path)
        {
            using (var file = File.OpenRead(path))
            {
                BinaryFormatter ser = new BinaryFormatter();
                return (List<T>)ser.Deserialize(file);
            }
        }
```

Comment: The problem is not the query itself, it's that you're performing it **1,000** times.

Comment: You stated that you've tried LINQ and PL/SQL and both are slow. I think you should quantify what "slow" is for your case and what type of performance you'd like to see. 

Also, you need to note how much data you are working with here as this will alter the optimum answer. And why are you doing this in a for loop (as noted by Servy)

Comment: I have to perform  many times. because I want best optimum reservation.

Comment: Profile the code. Then tell us what parts are actually meaningful to optimize.

Comment: @Ademsis - Can you post the code for derserialize<T>?

Comment: I edited my question ( for deserialize)

Comment: @Ademsis do every pass outputs different results from the previous pass?

Comment: @Ademsis also, title says Code first POCO. It's POCO, but what to you mean by "code first"?

Answer (score 0):

For starters...

Move your object initializers out of the loop.  You don't need to load the collections 1000 times.

Change

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
   var orders = deserialize<Order>(@"C:\orders.bin");
   var stocks = deserialize<Stock>(@"C:\Stocks.bin");
```

to

```
var orders = deserialize<Order>(@"C:\orders.bin");
var stocks = deserialize<Stock>(@"C:\Stocks.bin");
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
{
    ...
```

I came to this realization because you are loading the same file on each pass, which is expensive.  You only need to load them once each.

Comment: You should also be able to get some performance gain by using `Parallel.For` rather than `for` if you are running on > 1 CPU.

Comment: If these objects defer execution (which is quite plausible if they return `IEnumerable` or `IQueryable`) then this wouldn't change a thing.

Comment: @Servy, my answer, or Eric's comment?  Moving the loading out of the loop most certainly would change a lot.  Unless deserialize<T>().. is internally caching it and just returning the accessor on each repeated call, which I doubt.

Comment: @Ryios I was referring to your answer.  Moving the call out of the loop wouldn't do anything if its deferring execution.  It would still do all of the work every time it was iterated.

Comment: thanks Ryios, but I am sorry I wrote it wrong into forum. Already it.

Comment: I am going to try parallel.For.